# Using new zurb foundation 6 with yeoman / grunt

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to include zurb-foundation 6 into a yeoman generated project running grunt. Using `bower install foundation-sites --save` adds the following files:

1. On the app/index.html  `<script src="bower_components/what-input/what-input.js"></script>` and
2. on the app/styles/main.scss `@import "foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss";`

The resultant main.css does not contain all the code for zurb-foundation.

- How can i add all the required files from foundation onto the main.css?
- How can I initialize foundation into the site?

The above should be done using grunt or gulp so i don't have to manually write the code for every project.

Comment: also see: https://github.com/bassjobsen/generator-foundation6

Comment: Aha! cool. will give it a try.

Comment: @BassJobsen thanks alot. The generator works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should 
`@import foundation-sites/foundation-sites.scss` 
instead of 
`@import "foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss";`

or

`@import foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss`
and add `@include foundation-everything;` in your main.scss file.

Check this for further explanation:
[Gulp-sass not compiling Foundation 6 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919299/gulp-sass-not-compiling-foundation-6-properly/33937639)

Comment: This generator https://github.com/bassjobsen/generator-foundation6 does the above also.